# Why this code runs without error? I am updating UI from doInBackground of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was experimenting with the AsyncTask and found an unusual scenario, here is my code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var textView:TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        val task = MyAsyncTask()
        task.execute()
    }

    inner class MyAsyncTask:AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
            //Thread.sleep(3000)
            textView.text ="From AsyncTask"
            return "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

It worked!!, see the Thread.sleep is commented but if I uncomment it then the usual error what we know

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Why is so, if anybody know please share your feedback. Thanks

Comment: you are out of context of Main/ UI thread. When you initialize your task, pass Caller's context in the object initialization too

Comment: Guys, run the added code (exact code) and give your feedback. please read the question carefully. Thanks

Comment: changes on UI thread are not allowed in doInBackround(), use preExecute or postExecute for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's about the timing. When you comment Thread.sleep(3000), your view is not ready and connected with your activity, thus this version of code just updates a view that is yet to exist in UI.

However, after some time passes, UI would be started and when you update your view in doInBackground(), you will receive the exception that states *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views*. This also justifies the exception you got when you uncomment Thread.sleep(3000)

Comment: don't you think, if the view is not present it will throw null pointer exception? I think view is already created in the onCreate().

Comment: No. Actually, view is created but it's not binded to UI yet, so it assumes the view is created by background thread(AsynTask in this case) rather than UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

because when you're calling `Thread.sleep` in the following code:

```
inner class MyAsyncTask:AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {

        Thread.sleep(3000)
        textView.text ="From AsyncTask"
        ...
    }
}
```

it will run on current thread, which is a background thread of AsyncTask. You can see that in the [Thread.sleep](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#sleep(long,%20int)) documentation:

> public static void sleep (long millis,
>                       int nanos)
>
> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds plus the specified
>   number of nanoseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system
>   timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any
>   monitors.

So, the next code will switch to the background thread too:

```
textView.text ="From AsyncTask"
```

which will raise the exception.

Comment: when the Thread.sleep is commented, what is happening then , why is it working?

Comment: that is because `textView` still attached to UI thread when you're using inner class.

Answer (score -1):

As the exception clearly says :

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

`AsyncTask` `doInBackground` runs in separate background thread which don't have nothing to do with Main Thread now all the UI related work should be done on Main thread so rather then `settext` on `doInBackground` do it in `onpostexecute`.